# PHP gets only one file from multiple fileupload requests at once

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, jquery-file-upload, multiple-file-upload

So I am trying to **upload multiple files**,

Am controlling the files uploaded by the user via the `SESSION` variable in **codeigniter**, *by setting the session variable to hold the name of the file every time a file is uploaded* and merging it with the former file names if available , thus creating an Array of files uploaded by the user in a separate session .

And here is what i have...

```
if (!$this->upload->do_upload("user_file")) {
           //I do stuff that handles the failure
        }else{
                $data = $this->upload->data();
                //
                //Grab the TEMP file
                $array[] = array('filename'=>$data['file_name']);

                //Add the temp file to the session

                if($this->session->userdata('uploaded_files')){
                    $temp_file = $this->session->userdata('uploaded_files');
                    $this->session->set_userdata('uploaded_files',array_merge($array,$temp_file));

                }else{
                    //no need to merge since its the first one
                    $this->session->set_userdata('uploaded_files',$array);
                }
        }
```

My problem is that when PHP gets multiple request at the same time , it handles only the first one in the queue
[image: Only takes one in the finish line]

And when i give it one request at a time it takes all of them
[image: Takes all of them]

So i don't have the guarantee that the files will finish to upload at different times , errrm ... how can i make my array to have all the file names uploaded without considering the finish time, perhaps using session is not a good approach?

PS: At the server side all my files are there including the ones that did not get into the array of the uploaded FILES

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the file names from the $_FILES variable using the 'name' index (e.g. $_FILES['myfile1']['name']).

Comment: **Thank you for responding**,  but getting the file name of the uploaded file is not a problem , getting the names **concurrently** is the main problem , perhaps using **ci-sessions** is a bit slow ? i cant tell :(

Comment: @Fahad Could you clarify your need? What do you want to do with the names?

Comment: i need an **array of names** for **every user session** , so that i can **work with the files later** for instance ---    
_send them via mail_ ,   
_compress them and return them back_ , 
_batch processing on multiple files i.e cropping multiple images at once , converting multiple videos to mp3_

Comment: If you have to proccess them at a later point then one approach would be to store them temporarly since you are already uploading them anyway. Store the names in the session if you need after you're done uploading.

Comment: Unfortunately that is what I am doing --- (_Storing the names in a session_ ), but the names **fail to enter** into my **session** array ...  since they are coming in **simultaneously** rather they only **succeed** to enter if the uploaded files differ in their finishing time i.e i have illustrated this above.